# How to make eval() inside of an iframe safe?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, xss

My goal (without the use of webapps or Node.js) is to have it so that I can run user-created Javascript code that can reference external libraries (ie. Google Maps API), send variables from the main webpage to the iframe, and have zero interaction coming from the iframe to main webpage (ie. popups). I'm using eval to execute within an iframe to create an isolated environment.

On my main page, I plan on accessing sensitive data stored on AWS. Is this current setup good enough to prevent XSS and any breach of database info (this is my main purpose for doing this)?  Or are there any notable flaws in the way that it is sandboxed? What can I do to make it safer? Suggestions are welcome. The relevant code is below. Thanks.

I've tried using [this](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter) and [this](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/sandbox/), but it seems that they are not very secure and is hard to use external libraries in them.

index.html (main webpage):

```
<iframe id="sandbox-iframe" src="sandbox.html" frameBorder="0" style="flex-grow: 1; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: calc(100% - 30px)" sandbox="allow-scripts" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></iframe>

<script type="module" lang="js">
   const iframe = document.getElementById('sandbox-iframe');
   var myString = "Hello from the parent page!";
   iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(myString, '*');
</script>
```

sandbox.html (sandboxed webpage):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=Map"></script>
<script type="module" lang="js">
   var receivedString = ""; 
   window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 
      receivedString = event.data; 
      console.log('Received string:', receivedString); 
      eval(receivedString);
   });
</script>
```